# How to download all images from web page in C?

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

I have a really difficult problem for me... I hope that for more experienced programmers in C it's not a problem. I have to create a program (in as easy way as possible) which download all images from some web page.
This program must be in C (not C++ or any other language).

I find cURL library to download the source code but I don't have any idea how to download images.

ETID: only need to get all images with .jpg, .gif and .png extensions

Please help me. I am unexperienced programmer so please for a clear answers.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/types.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>
#include <string>

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

int main(void) {
    CURL *curl;
    FILE *fp;
    CURLcode res;
    char *url = "http://localhost/image.jpeg";
    char outfilename[] = "saveimage.jpeg";
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* always cleanup */
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can try use [`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) for download all images.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

     char command[] = "wget -A png,jpeg,jpg,gif -r http://www.freeimages.com/";  
     system(command); 
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's a solution if I know the url of image but I have to download all files from web page and I don't know URLs. This program should be universal.

Comment: @Virgin Ok..So for this you need to parse HTML page first. See answer of Basile Strankevitch.

Comment: Ok but as I wrote I don't know very well C language and I haven't any idea how to cut out the URLs with  .jpg, .gif and .png extensions

Comment: @Virgin ok...have updated answer but have not tested it.

Comment: Thanks but I'm affraid that this command not works when we compile program under Linux. Any other idea?

Comment: @Virgin It should work in linux. I have test it. See my updated answer for demo.It will create `www.freeimages.com` directory and save all images in that.Which Linux distro you used?

Comment: @Jayesh: I believe the goal of the homework is to avoid `wget` and learn how to parse some *simple* HTML in *C* code!

Comment: Sorry I have a bug with my terminal. All works you are amazing :) Thank you

Comment: @Virgin It's not bad to reject answers after accepting it two times.:)

Comment: sorry it was accidentally

Answer (score 0):

You can use [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) both for textual content (e.g. of mime type `text/html`) and for images (e.g. of mime type `image/jpeg`). Read [libcurl tutorial](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-tutorial.html). You might also want to study the source code of [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)

You probably need to fetch the entire content of some URL into a buffer. You'll probably need to keep the filled size of that buffer, and grow it (using `malloc`, `calloc` or maybe `realloc`).

You probably want to fetch the HTML page first, then parse somehow its HTML content and look for `<img` tags. (You might start using [strstr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/strstr.html) to  repeatedly find the `<img` string; you would also use [snprintf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/snprintf.html) to build some strings). Then, parse their `src=` attribute, and try to compute an URL from it.

Something like

```
 const char* pagecontent;
 /// retrieve a page content using CURL,
 /// check that its mime type is text/html,
 char* imgtag = NULL;
 for (imgtag = strstr(pagecontent, "<img ");
      imgtag != NULL;
      imgtag = strstr(imgtag+4, "<img "))
   {
     char* srcattr = strstr(imgtag, "src=");
     if (srcattr) {
         /// parse the src just after srcattr+4
         /// build an URL for the image using snprintf
         /// retreive that image using libcurl
```

Obviously, you need to understand a bit of [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML).

In practice, looking for `<img>` tags is not fail-proof. Some sites are [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) mostly and could fetch their images using AJAX requests.

<sup>(actually I believe that because of AJAX or embedded Javascript finding *all* images is *undecidable*, and could probably be proven equivalent to the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem))</sup>

If you are newbie in C, don't forget to compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` ....) and learn how to use the debugger (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: I understand HTML more than programming in C. Everything what you wrote is logical, but I don't know C very well and I don't know how to cut out all URLs with img extends

Comment: Could you tell me how can I looking for <img>? We could skip AJAX because that program have to be really easy.

Comment: Use `strstr(s, "<img")` to find in string `s` the first occurrence of literal string `"<img"` -without the quotes ... Then use again `strstr` to find `src=` etc.

Comment: I guess that it is easy for you but for me unfortunately not. Could you give me some example. I will be really grateful

Comment: Thank you so much it is that what I expected :)